# How to save data entered via toastUI calendar in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, calendar

I´m trying to build a booking system for a tennis court by using the toastUI-package in a shiny-app. Users should be able to enter their booking dates on the calendar and also see existing bookings.

I managed to show the calendar in shiny and data can be entered via popups.

My questions:

1. how can I store the entered dates? Somehow I have to include a dataframe in which one could store the entered data.
2. when data is entered via the popup and then updated via the edit button on the pupup, one can not delete it anymore. However, if the dates are updated via drag and drop, it works. Any ideas how to solve that problem?

here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(toastui)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("Buchungssystem"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Platz 1",
             calendarOutput("tennis1")
             ),
    )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$tennis1 <- renderCalendar({
      calendar(
        isReadOnly = F,
        scheduleView = "time",
        defaultDate = Sys.Date(),
        view = "week",
        navigation = T,
        navOpts =  navigation_options(today_label = "heute", prev_label = "Woche zurück", next_label = "Woche vor", fmt_date = "DD/MM/YYYY", sep_date = " - "),
        useDetailPopup = T,
        useCreationPopup = T
      ) %>%
        cal_week_options(startDayOfWeek = 1, daynames = c("So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa"),hourStart = 7,hourEnd = 21)
    })
       
     observeEvent(input$tennis1_add, {
       str(input$tennis1_add)
       cal_proxy_add("tennis1", input$tennis1_add)
     })    
    observeEvent(input$tennis1_update, {
      str(input$tennis1_update)
      cal_proxy_update("tennis1", input$tennis1_update)
    })   
    observeEvent(input$tennis1_delete, {
      str(input$tennis1_delete)
      cal_proxy_delete("tennis1", input$tennis1_delete)
    })   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Would be really thankful for any hint. Maybe the question is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look here? you might be able to store to google sheets if you want to keep it simple. https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html#gsheets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).